# Access 2010 Popup Report always matches size of Report Design window

Tags: ms-access, report

I have always been mystified by how Access popup forms and reports seem to size themselves arbitrarily.  Today, I discovered that the report I'm working on is actually sizing itself to match the visible design area of the report's design view.  Detail fields are in tabular layout.  Detail section is 0.2", report width is 3.5", and there is a small header and footer.  Popup = Yes; Modal = No; Auto Resize = No.

When I drag the left border of the property box to increase the size of the property box, and then open in report view, this actually makes the report narrower!  I know I can open in report view, resize the borders, and save.  But whenever I open in design view again, the report size resets to the size of the visible design area.

I am not looking for a workaround (I already know I can resize programmatically).  I want to know if there is a fix to the above behavior.  Shouldn't it initially set the width to the *Width* property?  And the height to the height of all rows plus header/footer height?  Please tell me the above behavior is not by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's by design, and why wouldn't it?

With `Auto Resize = No`, the size of the popup window will be the window size you saved in design view. What else could it be?

If you want the popup window size to adapt to the form/report width, set `Auto Resize = Yes`. That's the usual way to handle popups.

The height of popup *continuous* forms/reports will still be determined by the height you save in design view.

Thinking about it, you probably have "tabbed document windows" set in the Access Options for the current database. With this option, you don't really have much control over the window size in design view.
If you must have popups with `Auto Resize = No`, you probably should switch to "overlapping windows". (I don't know the exact option names since I have a German Access).

Comment: Thank you.  I have been using Access for about 5 years now and always used "tabbed document windows".  Never realized that NOT doing so opens up the possibility of sizing your forms in design view this way.  I always figured that the size of the form was supposed to be the width of the beige design area that you can resize even if you use "tabbed document windows".  I'm humbled.  Thanks again.