# Sizing an Access Form window in Design View

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm working on a form for an Access database I'm putting together. In the Design View I've gotten the area covered with grid to be the right size for the form. When I go to Form View though, there's a ton of empty space on the right & bottom. How do I remove that empty space?

Here's what the form looks like in Design View for context:
[image: Design View]

Answering Andre's questions:
Popup? Currently yes, but I'm not dead set on that. It's also Modal for what that's worth.

Maximized? No, when I go to Form view it's got at least a couple inches from where the grid space stops in my screenshot though.

Tabbed or Seperate? Not sure I follow. If you're meaning is the Form opened on a tab in the Access main pane or in a seperate window it's seperate.

Comment: It depends: Is it a popup form? Is it maximized in the Access main window? Do you use tabbed windows or separate windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a separate window (popup or not-maximized), then setting the `Form.AutoResize` property to Yes should do it.

For some more info ("tabbed document windows" is an option for the current DB), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321906/3820271

Comment: Especially Form.AutoResize