# Continuous form height - Too tall

Tags: ms-access

For some reason my continuous form is nearly as long as my screen, even when I only have a few records. In design view, I can see that the detail section is supposedly only .333" so I'm not sure what is causing this. I'd prefer that the form size be dynamic, but would also settle for a static height at this point. Just want something less obnoxiously large. Anyone know a reason this might be happening and how to fix it?

[image: Design View]
[image: Form View]

Comment: In design view , grab the outside of the form and resize it to your desired height and save, before re-opening the form in normal view. Make sure you haven't got the `FitToScreen` format property set to Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access 2010 Popup Report always matches size of Report Design window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318578/access-2010-popup-report-always-matches-size-of-report-design-window)

Comment: @Minty, FitToScreen is already set to yes and the form was already dragged to the appropriate size in design view. Auto Resize is also set to yes.

Comment: @Andre Tried those changes. Did not work :(

Comment: If you have Fit to screen set to yes it WILL grow !

Comment: @Minty Just have to add I've lost count of how many times at work I've written "_not_" just for that one word to be ignored..... :)

Comment: @Minty Sorry about that. Regardless, changing fitToScreen to "No" doesn't change anything. I'd added images so you can see what is happening. I checked and the footer is the appropriate size, so the problem is in how the detail section is appearing.

Comment: Do you have "overlapping" windows (not "tabbed") set in the Current DB options? Only then can you actually set the form size in design view.

Comment: I am still looking for any way to change any section height in an Access continuous form.  So far, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in design view, adjust the window hight as desired and click "save" to save the changes. When just closing the form, Access doesn't see that something has changed.

**Added:**
To illutrate what I mean (after changing the database to use "Overlapping Windows"), here are some screenshots.

Tall window:

[image: tall window]

Adjust the hight as desired:

[image: shortened window]

Switch to design view of the shortened form (for example by right-clicking the header):

[image: shortened form]

Now, save the form, close it an re-open:

[image: viola]

The *AutoResize* property ensures that no "half detail rows" will be dieplayed when opering the form.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the issue. I have saved the form many times and it's still not the appropriate dimensions.

Comment: I did not mean the form size, I meant the design window.

Comment: ..... change the size of the form in the design window, or actually change the design window? Because if you're talking about the first, that's what I did. And if you're talking about the second, I have no clue what you mean. ':D

Comment: @Eleyna Allright, as you have no clue what I mean, you probably have configured the database to use "Tabbed Documents" instead of "Overlapping Windows". :-) You can change that under *File*, *Options*, *Current Database*. After re-opening the database file, you can do what I just added to my answer.

Comment: Late reponse, but I had tried that too and it didn't seem to work. Alas, I gave up as it doesn't alter the functionality of the database :P Thanks so much for all of your suggestions though!

Comment: I have tried all of these suggestions.  None of these allow me to set the size of the detail section.

Comment: @DougKimzey The hight of the details section can be set in the properties window, but that wasn't the topic here. The details section is repeated for every row of a continous form. The question was on how to reduce the number of such rows displeyed. Open the form in its own window (not as a tab), adjust the size as desired and press Ctrl+S to "save" the changes.

Comment: Wolfgang - I have tried that.  Nothing lets me alter the height of any section.  I cannot event change the height of the Form Header.

Comment: @DougKimzey If you can't do it, let someone else do it for you.

Comment: I am switching to a .NET front-end.  This should give me more granular control.  We were going to use Access as a rapid prototyping tool for PostgreSQL Db apps.  We seem to be spending too much time on issues that should be simple. Not really a time saver.

Comment: @DougKimzey Just an idea: You can't make a section smaller than the space occupied by its controls, so maybe there's a line/rectangle/textbox/label or whatever preventing you from resizing the section to the desired (smaller) hight.

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in design view. Set the forms border style to “sizable”. You don’t have to, but I would also in the format tab set auto size = no, fit to screen = no.

Now flip the form into regular view. At this point, re-size the form to as you want. Now hit ctrl-s, and close the form.

You can now re-launch the form, and you see the size you set sticks. However, because the border style is “sizable”, then users can re-size the form. If you don’t want this to occur, then open form in design view (after close and doing above steps). Now change the border style to “thin” and close the form. (Answer yes to save).

At this point, when you launch the form, your sized settings will stick, and you (and users) cannot re-size the form.

If you need to change the size, then simply follow the above steps again. Thus open in design view, set border type to sizeable, flip into regular form view. Size the form as desired, and then hit ctrl-s to “save/freeze” the size. As noted, change the border style back to thin if you wish to prevent users etc. from being able to re-size the form.