# Microsoft Access : form height size in view mode does not match the height in design mode

Tags: forms, ms-access, popup

I have designed an Access 2016 form with an embedded subform.

When displaying my (main) form (shown in 1st picture), I notice a space below the sub-form and above the "Form footer" that I cannot see in design mode (see 2nd picture).

I have no clue how I could get rid of this unncessary space. Can someone help me out to find out what I have missed in the design of my userform ?

Many thanks in advance.

[image: design mode] [image: display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to move the buttons from the form footer to the bottom of the detail section.
Then get rid of header & footer, and set the form to `Auto Resize = Yes`.

If you don't want to do this, you must set and save the display size (height) of the popup form in design view.

You can't do this with tabbed documents, you need to switch to overlapping windows:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-object-tabs-25074ab7-bcc8-466d-81aa-b6cf739715cb

(and then open the form non-maximized in design view.)

It may take a bit of trial & error to get the height exactly right in design view.

Similar question: [Access 2010 Popup Report always matches size of Report Design window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318578/access-2010-popup-report-always-matches-size-of-report-design-window)